# JSP/Java Ternary operator returning boolean and RegEx check within rendered property JSTL

Tags: jsp, boolean, jstl, ternary

Here is sample code that throws a Servlet Exception as invalid expression error.

data Types are thus:

```
boolean: bean1.isValid1
boolean: bean1.isValid2
boolean: bean1.isValidSubCondn

String: bean2.StringData1 
String: bean2.StringData2
```

want to use this inside JSTL tag:

```
 <x:div id="someID" 
               rendered='#{!bean1.isValid1 || bean1.isValid2 ? (bean1.isValidSubCondn ? bean2.StringData1.matches("^a|^b") : bean2.StringData2.matches("^c|^d") ) : "true"}'>
```

Now if this works, I would like to add a method call instead of doing the RegEx check within the JSP itself. That doesn't work either - probably has to do with the same syntax issue.

```
[ServletException in:/beanName.jsp] 
 Invalid expression:
  '${!bean1.booleanProperty1 && bean1.booleanProperty2? (beanInstance.booleanProperty3 ? beanName.methodName1(bean2.stringProperty) : beanName.methodName1(bean3.stringProperty) ) :'true'}''
```

My JSP code is thus:

```
   <x:div id="something" rendered="#{not bean1.booleanProperty1 or (bean1.booleanProperty2 ? (beanInstance.booleanProperty3 ? beanName.methodName1(bean2.stringProperty) : beanName.methodName1(bean3.stringProperty) )) :true}">
```

This doesn't work either:

```
   <x:div id="something" rendered="#{!bean1.booleanProperty1 || bean1.booleanProperty2 ? (beanInstance.booleanProperty3 ? beanName.methodName1(bean2.stringProperty) : beanName.methodName1(bean3.stringProperty) ) :true}">
```

The beanName.methodName1 is thus:

```
public boolean methodName1(String stringValuex) {
    if(stringValuex.matches("^A|^B"))
        { return true; }

   return false; 
 }
```

alternatively, I tried using the getter/setter method approach in the bean class, to get and set the property. Doesn't work in the JSP either. Not sure how to resolve. 
I need to perform a validation using a bean data of another class to display certain results.

Here is the setter/getter approach, need to figure out how to use this, then, in the JSP validation.

```
   <x:div id="something" rendered="#{!bean1.booleanProperty1 and bean1.booleanProperty2 ? (beanInstance.booleanProperty3 ? beanName.booleanFieldName(bean2.stringProperty) : beanName.booleanFieldName(bean3.stringProperty) ) : true}">
```

beanName.java class

```
 private boolean booleanFieldName = false;
   public boolean getbooleanFieldName() {
        return this.booleanFieldName;
    }

    public void setbooleanFieldName(String valueToTest) {
         if(valueToTest.matches("^a|^A"))
            { this.booleanFieldName= true;
            }
        this.booleanFieldName= false; 
    }
```

Comment: If you notice, they are two seperate questions. Very similar but different. The other one is attempting a method call inside the rendered attribute of tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix types in a ternary, and you are mixing boolean`with`String"true"`.

Try this, replacing `"true"` with `true`:

```
rendered='#{!bean1.isValid1 || bean1.isValid2 ? (bean1.isValidSubCondn ? bean2.StringData1.matches("^a|^b") : bean2.StringData2 .matches("^c|^d") ) : true}'>
```

Comment: This is still not fixing the issue. I see the same error. Am new to JSP, it appears to be a simple syntax issue.

Comment: The boolean check instead of string did need to be fixed, however I am  still unable to call methods. Am working on it!